# How to get parent selector with jquery.on('click'), base on the clicked element

Tags: jquery

I'm using `jQuery.on()`, and have the following code:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.link',function (event) {
    console.log($(this)); // Logs '.link'
});
```

How can i access to the '.parent' element in which the click was triggered?

`$(this)` returns the '.link' element

Comment: @Arth Correction, I was mixing up which answer answered which question. This question and answer pair look better to me than that linked duplicate.

Comment: @cpburnz Cool, no worries. I look up this exact question every couple of months.. delegateTarget is such a confusing name!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use closest():

```
$(this).closest('.parent');
```

Or use: `$(event.delegateTarget)` which will take into account multiple nested `.parent` elements.

If your element is an anchor tag, you have surely to prevent default behaviour.

Comment: Great answer, but I'd prefer it if `$(event.delegateTarget)` was presented as the primary solution not as an alternative