# jQuery on() - is event.delegateTarget the best way to get the main container of on() function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a HTML similar to this:

```
<div class="ajax_table_container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="ajax.php?action=delete&id=1" class="delete_element">DELETE</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="ajax.php?action=delete&id=2" class="delete_element">DELETE</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
$("div.ajax_table_container").on("click", "a.delete_element", function (event) {
    var adr = $(this).attr("href");    
    $(event.delegateTarget).html("TEST");
    return false;
});
```

In real application I'm reloading contents of the ajax request from the address provided in the link clicked.

My question is though, is the method I'm using the best to get the main div (with class `ajax_table_container`). I'm talking about the fragment: `event.delegateTarget`. Is there any better way of getting it in jQuery? (btw. I don't want to use `$('div.ajax_table_container')` here - there might be a couple of these divs on one page)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aD5Rc/)

**EDIT**: After getting some answers and checking google I would like to mark myself as duplicate ;-) Here: [How to get parent selector with jquery.on('click'), base on the clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431399/how-to-get-parent-selector-with-jquery-onclick-base-on-the-clicked-element)

Comment: *"I'm talking about the fragment: `event.delegateTarget`. Is there any better way of getting it in jQuery?"* Better how? This is exactly what `delegateTarget` is for, and it's a DOM element reference, so it's about as efficient as you could ask for. You seem to have a reason not to want to use it...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get parent selector with jquery.on('click'), base on the clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431399/how-to-get-parent-selector-with-jquery-onclick-base-on-the-clicked-element)

Comment: Yeah, after checking answers I found it's a possible duplicate. Well I don't have any reason NOT to use it, I just found delegateTarget experimentally by using `console.log(event)` and I didn't know too much about it, so I thought I should ask.

Comment: @ Kelu: Yeah, I did the duplicate mark that after your edit (I didn't know about the previous one until then), to get the process started foryou. :-) Yup, no reason not to use it, it's [documented](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your goal is to get the element on which you hooked the event, it's not only your best option, but nearly your only option.

Another option, which I'm not advocating, is to remember what you used in a variable that the event handler closes over:

```
var $container = $("div.ajax_table_container");
$container.on("click", "a.delete_element", function (event) {
    var adr = $(this).attr("href");    
    $container.html("TEST");
    return false;
});
```

But since jQuery gives you that handy [`delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/), that's what I'd use barring a good reason to use something else. The cost of passing an element reference (as opposed to a selector) into `$()` isn't large at all, it's likely whatever else you're doing in the handler washes out any overhead it adds.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, which is more preffered though, `delegateTarget` or `closest()` from Patsy Issa suggestion?

Comment: @KeluThatsall: `closest` has to do a lot more work matching elements against the selector (and you have to repeat the selector). I'd use `delegateTarget`, this is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest("div.ajax_table_container");
```

This will return the parent of the clicked link.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's another option. More expensive than `delegateTarget`, though.

Comment: Thank you, which is more preffered though?

Comment: @KeluThatsall I d go with delegateTarget, why make the extra operation when it's already available.

Comment: Well I guess you're right, it seems `delegateTarget` just passes it as a property while executing, when `closest` and `parents` are looking for the element, so they might be more time consuming with more complicated DOM

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here to register the event handler, the best option to get the element `ajax_table_container` where the currently-called jQuery event handler is attached is to use the [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) here.